# Dose Task create any thread on OS level?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I read about difference between task and thread:

> Thread represents an actual OS-level thread, with its own stack and
>   kernel resources. (technically, a CLR implementation could use fibers
>   instead, but no existing CLR does this) Thread allows the highest
>   degree of control Task class from the Task Parallel Library offers the
>   best of both worlds. Like the ThreadPool, a task does not create its
>   own OS thread.

So my question is Does Task create any thread on OS?

Comment: The TaskScheduler is responsible for creating threads for Tasks or reusing threads for tasks.

Comment: [Task Schedulers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) covers the basics.